# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0'

Tags: jpa, struts2, eclipselink, junit4, spring-3

Error creating bean with name

```
'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in URL [file:/E:/source-files-healthentic/securityadmin/build/test/classes/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/E:/source-files-healthentic/securityadmin/build/test/classes/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in URL [file:/E:/source-files-healthentic/securityadmin/build/test/classes/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/E:/source-files-healthentic/securityadmin/build/test/classes/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:411)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:271)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:268)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:881)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:597)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:366)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
    at org.apache.struts2.StrutsSpringTestCase.setupBeforeInitDispatcher(StrutsSpringTestCase.java:39)
    at org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase.setUp(StrutsTestCase.java:208)
    at healthentic.admin.action.StrutsSpringBase2Setup.setUp(StrutsSpringBase2Setup.java:128)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:/E:/source-files-healthentic/securityadmin/build/test/classes/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:411)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:271)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:268)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:266)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation.
    at org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.addTransformer(InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.java:88)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.addTransformer(SpringPersistenceUnitInfo.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:224)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1327)
```

I'm getting this error when running my application(using `Struts2 spring3 integrated and jpa eclipse` link ) junit test.... **how can i resolve this problem**................ kindly check ans suggest me....

Comment: include your Spring config file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error states,

"Must start with Java agent to use InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver. See Spring documentation."

so, you either need to use the Spring Java agent to start your JVM, or need to disable the InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver.

See,
[How to configure EclipseLink 2.0 and Spring 3.0.5 and Tomcat 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421829/how-to-configure-eclipselink-2-0-and-spring-3-0-5-and-tomcat-6)

For JPA weaving with EclipseLink, you can also use the static weaver, then no agent or instrumentation is required.

Comment: thankyou for ur reply.... i have resolved my problem after fix the version conflicts in my jar files.....

Comment: Hi could you please give the jar names.

Answer (score 5):

To help others with this issue,

I have he same problem after including some of the APIS thst uses later Spring (3.x.) versions to the existing project.

My application was started up successfully in one machine but failed on another machine. After investigating carefully we found this,

On the machine it was failing, the PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor was loaded from spring-dao-2.0.8.jar 
[Loaded org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor from file:/lib/spring-dao-2.0.8.jar]

Where as on the other machine it was loaded from spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
[Loaded org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor from file:/lib/spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar]

Then I tried removing the spring-dao-2.0.8.jar from the class-path and tried, it worked.
spring-dao-2.0.8.jar was an unnecessary dependency.

Regards
Lyju

Comment: I am facing somewhat the same issue. My error message says "exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(Ljava/util/LinkedHashSet;Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/class"  ...at the end instead of Java agent message.