# The role of spring-instrument-tomcat module

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

What's the role of the Spring module : spring-instrument-tomcat ?How does it work?I can't find anything about it on the web and in various books.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just stumbled across this documentation for it

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-aj-ltw-environments

oh and to provide some context, it basically has to do with getting eclipselink to work with spring on tomcat. here's another stack overflow thread about the subject for reference, but i got more out of the spring documentation

[How to configure EclipseLink 2.0 and Spring 3.0.5 and Tomcat 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421829/how-to-configure-eclipselink-2-0-and-spring-3-0-5-and-tomcat-6)

Comment: Tomcat 8 seems to include a class loader that spring can use to run the aspect weaver. So spring-tomcat-instrument is no longer required.

See
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/InstrumentableClassLoader.html