# Data is not getting inserted in JPA Spring weblogic

Tags: spring, jpa, eclipselink, jta

I have following configuration in application context

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="MY_DS" />
<context:load-time-weaver/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


<bean id="emf"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pu_TEST" />
</bean>
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Now my DAO Class

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDAO{

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
    @Transactional
    public void create(Employee entity) {
        LOG.error("Enitity Manager:create" + em);
        em.persist(entity);
        // em.flush(); if i use flush it saves
    } 
}
```

Now when I save the entity it does not say give any error but no data is updated into db.
I do not wish to use flush as entitymanager is injected  by spring and should perform flush at the end automatically which is not happening. correct my understanding.

Adding facade class may be issue is there, Does Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW has anything to do here?

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void process(){
    Employee e = factory.getEmployee();
    employeeDao.create(e);
}
```

On Debug after create method call it shows employee got primary key populated that mean db call has made but at the end it is not persisted.

Comment: Which Spring version are you using?

Comment: I am using Spring 3.2

Comment: The EntityManager is not hooked up to your transaction manager, and so isn't registering as a listener for when the transaction commits.  As mentioned in the answer below, em.joinTransaction() will work but it is a workaround, just like calling em.flush is.  You are missing the entityManagerFactory property passed to the TransactionManager as outlined here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421829/how-to-configure-eclipselink-2-0-and-spring-3-0-5-and-tomcat-6 or try setting the target server property http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_target_server.htm

Comment: I am using "org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager" it does not allow property of EMF.

Comment: Invalid property 'entityManagerFactory' of bean class [org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager]: Bean property 'entityManagerFactory' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

Answer (score 0):

Please try either of the 3 :

**1.Solution 1**

Please call  below code

```
em.joinTransaction();
```

just before

```
 em.persistEntity(entity);
```

**2.Solution 2**

make attribute readOnly=false in @Transactional

**3.Solution 3**

Try manually adding bean EmployeeDAO in spring xml file

or else you can try below:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
```

Comment: 2 & 3 are not working, do not want to use work around of 1

Comment: The problem over here is EntityManager is not able to get associated with the JTA Transaction. Another way , though its kind of manually starting a transaction such as em.getTransaction() and then beginning and committing transactions manually.

Comment: Please take a look at this post    https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=953940&view=next